# Diamond shorthand syntax not working javac

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, javac, diamond-operator

When I compile this:

```
LinkedBlockingDeque<Integer> q = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
```

in Eclipse Java EE Kepler version, everything works fine, but once I try to compile the same program in in the terminal with

> javac myProgram.java

in the command line, I receive a "illegal start of type" error, on the <>

I know the Diamond Shorthand came with java 7, so why would the terminal use the javac of java 6 and not 7? And how do I correct this permanently? I'm on Linux, Mint 15.

Running javac -version revealed this

```
~ $ javac -version
    javac 1.6.0_27
```

Comment: Try this link http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have two separate versions of java installed.  In Eclipse, you can specify the location of your JDK - which is set to 1.7.  However in the terminal, your PATH variable contains (first) the location of JDK 1.6.  As it looks like you're running linux/unix, try printing your `PATH` variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

You'll see in there path to JDK 1.6; path to JDK 1.7 may also be there but after the JDK 1.6 path.  Edit your `~/.profile` file and edit the path accordingly - remove JDK 1.6 and add JDK 1.7.

If, on the other hand, path to JDK 1.6 is set on the system level (e.g. in `/etc/profile`), then the easiest thing to do would be to add this line to your `~/.profile` file:

```
export PATH="/path/to/jdk1.7/bin:$PATH"
```

After editing this file, log out and log back in.

Comment: I added that line to ~/.profile and it worked after I logged in again, thanks for the detailed response

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the Java 7 bin directory to your `PATH` environment variable. Or maybe Java 6 is also in there and is *before* the Java 7 path.

Comment: java -version says I'm on version **1.7.0_21**. How to I add the javac to my PATH environment variable?

Comment: You have to add the `bin` directory of the `JDK` and not the `JRE` to the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score -1):

In eclipse.. Go to project properties -> Java Compiler and select the required java compiler version.

Comment: OP had no problem with Eclipse, but was asking about javac